# Pirkei Avot 5:17 - Defining controversies for the sake of Heaven

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, hillel

[Pirkei Avot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9671&st=&pgnum=543) 5:17, gives examples of an argument for the sake of heaven which is Shamai and Hillel. One not for the sake of Heaven is Korach and his congregants.

Perhaps I am picking on the grammar, with the usage of the letter ו which I take to mean "and". There seems to be a lack of "parallelism", here.

Hillel and Shamai had disputes against each other. But, Korach did not have a dispute against his congregants. The congregants joined him and they, together had a dispute against Moshe and Aharaon?

Is the Mishnah implying something else here by stating something that is not obvious from reading the event of Korach in the Torah? Did Korach have a dispute with his own congregants?

Comment: I wrote about Korach years ago -- this is one snippet, "That the Mishna in Avot 5:17 points to the machloket not between Moshe and Korach, but Korach and his followers as one not  l’shem shamayim points out that the machloket  between Moshe  and Korach might have been positive and not a division, one whose sofah was  l’hitkayem.

Comment: @Danno I am interested in any points surrounding the snip. When and if possible, provide a link. Offhand, it doesn't sound like a direct answer to my question, but it probably has good tangential points. Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: I only included it as a comment since it doesn't address anything head on. IMHO Korach, a tzaddik, argued in terms of motivation with his "followers" who were interested in rank and privilege.

Comment: @Danno I differ. See Rash"i who emphasizes Targum's use of the word "plag". He says that he separated himself from everyone else.

Comment: I can send you the entire piece if you'd like. I do discuss the opening verb, though it might not be exactly the point you are making. Just let me know how to get the piece to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tosfot Yom Tov [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&st=&pgnum=397&hilite=) explains this very precisely in name of the Midrash Shmuel, itself in name of the R.I. Lirma:

> לא הזכיר צד שני של מחלוקת שהם משה ואהרון כמו שזכר בחלוקה ראשונה שני הצדדים לפי שבכאן אינם שוים שמשה ואהרון כוונתם לשמים הייתה. ולא הייתה בהם שום בחינה שלא לשם שמים. מדרש שמואל בשם הר"י לירמה. ‏
>
> The fact that the second side of this controversy is not mentioned as for the first controversy, is that can we have an asymmetry concerning the intent of the sides. Moshe and Aharon were entirely disinterested

Noam Elimelech in the end of the book, called Likute Shoshanim wrote [see rignt column](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38141&st=&pgnum=138&hilite=) :

> לכאורה היה לו לומר מחלוקת קורח ועדתו עם משה כמו שבמחלוקת לשם שמים נאמר מחלוקת הלל ושמאי אך הענין עינינו רואים כמה בעלי מחלוקת העומדים על הצדיקים ודוברים על הצדיק בגאוה ובוז. ומי יודע אם כוונתם כדי לקנתר ולבזות צדיקי אמת אם כוונתם לשמים, כאשר יגידו בפיהם כמה בני אדם שכוונתם לשמים וגם לומדי תורה נמצאים במחלוקת זו באומרם כוונתם לשמים. כי כן הוא הדרך של הצדיקים גמורים ואמיתיים שנפשם קשורה זה בזה באהבה רבה וחביבות ואוהב את חברו יותר מגופו ולא יקנא איש באחיו בראותו גדולת חברו ישמח נפשו ויגל בלבבו ויצפה עוד לגדולתו שיתגדל ויתנשא יותר ויותר אבל אם אנו רואים בני אדם בעלי מחלוקת שאין להם   התחברות רק להמחלוקת. יבערו כולם כאחד אבל בשאר התחברות לבביהם פרודות וחלוקות ולא יוכל אחד לראות בגדולת חבירו ויתאוה תאוה ליקום אשר ברגליהם זה ממונו וגדולת חברו יהי לו. זה האות שאש התבערה המצה ומריבה אשר תבער בעדם יחד שכם אחד אין זה כי אם רוע לב וזדון לבם השיאם קנאת איש מרעהו לדבר על הצדיקים עובדי ה' באמתץ **וזהו שאמר התנא איזה מחלוקת שאינה לשם שמים זו מחלוקת קורח ועדתו ר"ל שהם היו ר"ן איש והתאוו כל אחד כהונה גדולה כפירש"י ז"ל ונמצא גם ביניהם היה ליבם פרודות וחלוקות** רק נגד משה רבינו היו כולם כאחד בעצה רעה לחלוק עליו: וזהו קרח ועדתו **רמז כנזכר לעיל שהיו לב קרח ועדתו נפרדות זה מזה** אבל צדיקים לבביהם דבוקות זה בזה וכל מעשיהם לשם שמים וקל להבין. ‏
>
> summary: Korach and his group were united in the jealousy for the greatness of Aharon, but apart from this there was no bonds of friendship between one another. Each of them wanted to be Kohen Gadol and one was adverse for another. The Mishna enhance this fact that there was a controversy against Moshe, but also a lot of controversies inside the group.

Following the first pshat, the expression is truncated קורח וכל עדתו and the end עם משה is skipped because Moshe was disinterested.

Following the second pshat, we can add that the form of the statement contains an allusion to inner controversies inside the Korach's group, so the ואו is good, not קורח, כל עדתו ומשה.

Comment: Great research. This is also a clear example that it takes 2 peole to argue. Sometimes, the best solution to an argument is to walk away, as, apparently, Moshe did.

Comment: @DanF great comment from pshat and remez point of view!